# Can' fetch row role from database using Nette

Tags: php, database

I got my table like this:

```
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`role` varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`email`)
```

and I have data like this

```
1 | admin | 702a7853691c23ec922e408b1322d2cc4fa1d101 | name@doman.sk | guest
```

I try to SELECT data:

```
$row = $this->database->table('users')->where('username', $username)->fetch();
```

I can access:

```
$row->email,$row->username,$row->password
```

but i can't access :

```
$row->role
```

I can't find sollution for this.

Comment: Can you try this:     fetchAll()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you are using which mvc or cms. But i know that after each select you must fetch your data. See your documents for fetch syntax.

Comment: I fetch data(see my answer). I use MVC. I read docu for nette but I can't fetch all rows , I just fetch all rows without last one .

Comment: You must use this :
fetchAll( string $args )